# How to trigger OnWebAuthentication

Tags: php, authentication, plugins, modx-revolution

I've dabbled with Modx before but this is the first time I've ever tried my hand at a plugin.

I've written the following plugin to authenticate users against a third party database. The System Events OnWebAuthentication is enabled.

```
if ($modx->event->name == 'OnWebAuthentication') {

        $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'{urlhere}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);        

    if($output == '1')
    {
               $modx->event->output(true);
    }else{
           $modx->event->output(false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain what you are trying to do, so I'll explain the event trigger.

As you can see in [login.class.php](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/a0acb61215447c0d8cdcfd3b8cb398237eb7928e/core/model/modx/processors/security/login.class.php#L236), this event is triggered when a user is authenticated e.i. logged in. However, this event is not triggered if `isMgr` is true. `isMgr` is defined as `($this->loginContext == 'mgr')`. This means that if the user is logged into the context mgr (e.g. by logging into `/manager`), the event will not be triggered, but `OnManagerAuthentication` will.

If you want to log a user in, the easiest way to do this is by using the [Login extra](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/login). There are several [examples](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/login/login.login) in the wiki. You can also specify which contexts they should log into too.